# Image resize optimization causes memory usage to sky rocket

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, xamarin.ios, uiimage

I made a function that takes an original image and resizes it to 3 different zoom scales -> 16x, 10x, and 4x.  For a better understanding, continue reading this paragraph.  Let's say the original image is 1000x1000.  I declare that at 1x zoom it's dimensions will be 50x50.  That means 4x zoom will be 200x200, 10x zoom will be 500x500 and 16x zoom will be 800x800.  So my function needs to resize the original 1000x1000 down to 800x800, then down to 500x500, then down to 200x200.  Please note I have done this successfully and **my question is regarding memory usage**.

Below I have two methods of doing so.  Both methods work, but one causes a HUGE memory usage bloat using approximately 3x/4x more memory than the other...  I like the 2nd method better, because it loads significantly faster than the first method because it's not resizing each of the 3 images from the original image, instead it's resizing them from the previously resized image.

Notes:  I'm using Xcode Instruments to measure memory usage.  The ImageResizer Class contains a function called "Resize" which resizes the Image.

Method 1.)

```
    public List<UIImage> InitImageList_BFObjects ( UIImage image, SizeF frameSize )
    {
        List<UIImage> listOfImages = new List<UIImage>();

        for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        {
            if ( i == 0 )
                zoomScale = 16f;
            else if ( i == 1 )
                zoomScale = 10f;
            else// if ( i == 2 )
                zoomScale = 4f;

            Resizer = new ImageResizer(image);
            Resizer.Resize(frameSize.Width * zoomScale, frameSize.Height * zoomScale);
            UIImage resizedImage = Resizer.ModifiedImage;
            listOfImages.Insert(0, resizedImage);

        }

        return listOfImages;
    }
```

Method 1 works and uses very little memory usage.  I ran this with a group of about 20 images.  My app had about 14mb of memory usage after this loaded (using Xcodes Instruments to examine memory usage)

Method 2.)

```
    public List<UIImage> InitImageList_BFObjects ( UIImage image, SizeF frameSize )
    {
        List<UIImage> listOfImages = new List<UIImage>();

        for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        {
            if ( i == 0 )
                zoomScale = 16f;
            else if ( i == 1 )
                zoomScale = 10f;
            else// if ( i == 2 )
                zoomScale = 4f;


            if ( listOfImages.Count == 0 )
            {
                Resizer = new ImageResizer(image);
                Resizer.Resize(frameSize.Width * zoomScale, frameSize.Height * zoomScale);
                UIImage resizedImage = Resizer.ModifiedImage;
                listOfImages.Insert(0, resizedImage);
            }
            else
            {
                // THIS LINE CONTAINS THE MAIN DIFFERENCE BETWEEN METHOD 1 AND METHOD 2
                // Notice how it resizes from the most recent image from listOfImages rather than the original image
                Resizer = new ImageResizer(listOfImages[0]);
                Resizer.Resize(frameSize.Width * zoomScale, frameSize.Height * zoomScale);
                UIImage resizedImage = Resizer.ModifiedImage;
                listOfImages.Insert(0, resizedImage);
            }
        }

        return listOfImages;
    }
```

Method 2 works but the memory usage sky rockets!  I ran this with the same group of about 20 images.  My app had over 60mb of memory usage after this loaded (using Xcodes Instruments to examine memory usage)  Why is the memory usage so high?  What is it about Method 2 that causes the memory to sky rocket?  It's almost as if a variable is not getting cleaned up properly

* Additional Information, ImageResizer Class ****

I cut out the non-needed functions from my ImageResizer Class and renamed it "ImageResizer_Abridged".  I even switched over to using this class to make sure I didn't accidentally cut out anything needed.

```
public class ImageResizer_Abridged
{
    UIImage originalImage  = null;
    UIImage modifiedImage = null;

    public ImageResizer_Abridged ( UIImage image )
    {
        this.originalImage = image;
        this.modifiedImage = image;
    }   

    /// <summary>
    /// strech resize
    /// </summary>
    public void Resize( float width, float height )
    {
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext( new SizeF( width, height ) );
        //
        modifiedImage.Draw( new RectangleF( 0,0, width, height ) );
        modifiedImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        //
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
    }

    public UIImage OriginalImage 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.originalImage;
        }
    }

    public UIImage ModifiedImage 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.modifiedImage;
        }
    }
}
```

I created a simplified test project showing this problem *******

Here is a dropbox link to the project:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/4w7d87nn0aafph9/TestMemory.zip

Here is Method 1's Xcode Instruments screen shot as evidence (9 mb memory usage):
http://i88.photobucket.com/albums/k194/lampshade9909/AllImagesResizedFromOriginalImage_zps585228c6.jpg

Here is Method 2's Xcode Instruments screens hot as evidence (55 mb memory usage):
http://i88.photobucket.com/albums/k194/lampshade9909/SignificantIncreaseInMemoryUsage_zps19034bad.jpg

Below is the code block needed to run the test project

```
        // Initialize My List of Images
        ListOfImages = new List<UIImage>();

        for ( int i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
        {
            // Create a UIImage Containing my original Image
            UIImage originalImage = UIImage.FromFile ("b2Bomber.png");
            float newWidth = 100f;
            float newHeight = 40f;
            float zoomScale;
            float resizedWidth, resizedHeight;

            UIImage resizedImage1;
            UIImage resizedImage2;

            // Basically, I want to take the originalImage Image and resize it twice.  
            // Method 1.) Resize the originalImage and save it as ResizedImage1.  Resize the originalImage and save it as ResizedImage2.  We're finished!
            // Method 2.) Resize the originalImage and save it as ResizedImage1.  Resize ResizedImage1 and save it as ResizedImage2.  We're finished!

            // The pro to Method 1 is that we get the best possible quaility on all resized images.  The con is, this takes a long time if we're doing dozens of very large images
            // The pro to Method 2 is that it's faster than Method 1.  This is why I want to use Method 2, it's speed.  But it has a HUGE con, it's memory usage. 
            // Please run this project on an iPad connected to XCodes Instruments to monitor memory usage and see what I mean 

            zoomScale = 10f;
            resizedWidth = newWidth*zoomScale;
            resizedHeight = newHeight*zoomScale;
            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext( new SizeF( resizedWidth, resizedHeight ) );
            originalImage.Draw( new RectangleF( 0, 0, resizedWidth, resizedHeight ) );
            resizedImage1 = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphics.EndImageContext();



            zoomScale = 4f;
            resizedWidth = newWidth*zoomScale;
            resizedHeight = newHeight*zoomScale;
            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext( new SizeF( resizedWidth, resizedHeight ) );

            // Run this project on an iPad and examine the memory usage in XCode's Instruments.  
            // The Real Memory Usage will be aroud 9 MB.  
            // Uncomment this "originalImage.Draw" line to see this happening, make sure to comment out the "resizedImage1.Draw" line

            // originalImage.Draw( new RectangleF( 0, 0, resizedWidth, resizedHeight ) );


            // Run this project on an iPad and examine the memory usage in XCode's Instruments.  
            // The Real Memory Usage will be aroud 55 MB!!  
            // My question is, why does the memory sky rocket when doing this, and how can I prevent the memory from sky rocketing??
            // My App requires me to resize around a hundred images and I want to be able to resize an already resized image (like in this example) without the memory usage sky rocketing like this...
            // Uncomment this "resizedImage1.Draw" line to see this happening, make sure to comment out the "originalImage.Draw" line

            resizedImage1.Draw( new RectangleF( 0, 0, resizedWidth, resizedHeight ) );
            resizedImage2 = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphics.EndImageContext();


            // Add my resized images to the list of Images
            ListOfImages.Add (resizedImage1);
            ListOfImages.Add (resizedImage2);
        }
```

Comment: Note that creating reductions of reductions almost always produces lower image quality than producing reductions directly from the original image.

Comment: I tested this out, and I couldn't "see" a difference when looking at the images on my iPad.  But I totally agree with your statement.

Comment: It's hard to answer without seeing your `Resize` method - it could be a bug but I suspect a caching issue.

Comment: I added the ImageResizer_Abridged Class to show you the details of what's inside the Resize method.

Comment: Your method 2 will create the first image at 16x, then the second (which is based on the first image) at 160x (i.e. 10*16). You have to base it off the original image, or do some funkyness like `zoomScale = 10f / 16f`.

Comment: CodeNaked, I am basing it off the original size.  The frameSize that's passed into the function contains the size at 1x.  in my example at the top of the question I said my original size is 50x50 (for example).  So it's 50x4, then 50x10, then 50x16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about your `Resize` code but I have seen `Scale` do *strange* thing. It's not really strange, once you dig into it, but it's definitively not obvious.

Creating an `UIImage` *can* be very cheap, memory wise, as long as its backing `CGImage` is not created. IOW iOS *might* not **immediately** allocate a new `CGImage` backing image that match the new size. That allocation will be **differed** until the `CGImage` is needed.

In such case it's possible for some code (like your method 1) to require almost no additional memory when scaling up. However your 2nd method is using a scaled-up image (and will need to allocate the backing `CGImage` to do so) so it end up requiring the memory *earlier*.

**How can you check for this ?**

Compare your `resizedImage.Size` with the `resizedImage.CGImage.Size`. If they don't match then you're likely hitting caching.

**Notes**

- I say *might* because the caching logic is *unknown* (undocumented). I know that this can differ from running on the simulator and devices - and it also vary between iOS versions;
- Caching is a good thing - but it can be surprising :-) I just wish this was documented.

Comment: Assuming caching is the issue, is there anyway I can recreate a new UIImage from that resized image without creating the backing CGImage?  It seems liek when I try that, it is bringing in the backing CGImage stuff (and the bloating memory usage...)  I tried doing UIIMage recreatedImage = new UIImage(resizedImage.CGImage);

After the resize, I did check the resizedImage.Size and compared it with the resizedImage.CGImage.Size.  They came out to be equal though...  Is it possible that the sizes are the same and caching is still the issue?  PS:  I added more detailed information above

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether Resizer implements the Dispose() method? I don't see you disposing it anywhere.

I believe your new code line is implementing the Zoom on the entire image, hence the increased memory usage.

Resizer is zooming the ENTIRE image at the new zoomed in scale, so that an incoming 4MB image is zoomed to 8MB, 16MB and 32MB, consuming your memory.

Comment: The ImageResizer class does not have a Dispose method implementation.  I tried setting several things to null and calling GC.Collect but what I had tried didn't seem to help...  Maybe I missed something

Comment: Pieter, are you talking about the line of "Resizer = new ImageResizer(listOfImages[0]);"?  What do you mean, implementing the zoom on the entire image?  I'm delaring a new instance of the ImageResizer class here and sending only the image that's in the first index of listOfImages.  So shouldn't it only resize listOfImages[0]?

Comment: Yes, but is zooming the ENTIRE image at the new zoomed in scale, so that an incoming 4MB image is zoomed to 8MB, 16MB and 32MB, consuming your memory.

Comment: @Brian: Is the expanded answer more suitable?

Answer (score 0):

`UIImage` implements `IDisposable`, so something will have to `Dispose` of it eventually. The `Resize` method appears to "lose" the reference to `modifiedImage`, so I'm going to `Dispose()` it. Hopefully the caller is doing the same to all images in the list returned by `InitImageList_BFObjects` when it's done with them. Or *that* class implements `IDisposable` and it's kicked up the line of who has to deal with it. But rest assured, these images being created need to be `Dispose()`d somewhere sometime.

```
public class ImageResizer_Abridged
{
    private readonly UIImage originalImage;

    private UIImage modifiedImage;

    public ImageResizer_Abridged(UIImage image)
    {
        this.originalImage = image;
        this.modifiedImage = image;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// stretch resize
    /// </summary>
    public void Resize(float width, float height)
    {
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(new SizeF(width, height));
        //
        var oldImage = this.modifiedImage;
        this.modifiedImage.Draw(new RectangleF(0, 0, width, height));
        this.modifiedImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        oldImage.Dispose();
        //
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
    }

    public UIImage OriginalImage
    {
        get
        {
            return this.originalImage;
        }
    }

    public UIImage ModifiedImage
    {
        get
        {
            return this.modifiedImage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this ->> var oldImage = this.modifiedImage; ......  oldImage.Dispose();  My Images disapear.  Is that because oldImage is pointing to this.modifiedImage resulting in it disposing of this.modifiedImage?

Comment: That's an excellent question. I only did a little digging around to find what `UIImage` is - I don't do MonoTouch development. I guess the real question is how does `UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` operate under the hood - is it just returning the same instance of `this.modifiedImage` or is it creating a new `UIImage` altogether? I'm guessing from your experience there, it's the former. That being the case, just keep your mind on the initial exposition I give rather than the code.